# Strange ClassCastException

Tags: java, generics, exception, type-inference, classcastexception

This:

```
Timerange longest = Timerange.longest(breaks);
if (longest.durationInHours() >= MIN_FREE_HOURS)
    return true;
```

is OK.

But this:

```
if (Timerange.longest(breaks).durationInHours() >= MIN_FREE_HOURS)
    return true;
```

gives:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Do you know **why**?!

For simplicity:

```
public static final <T extends Timerange> T longest(List<T> timeranges) {
    return timeranges.get(0);
}
```

Breaks:

```
List<Duty> breaks = week.substract(weekDuties);
```

Comment: How about showing a complete example which exhibits the problem? In particular, the declaration of breaks is missing.

Comment: List<Duty> breaks = week.substract(weekDuties);

Comment: Does `Duty` extend `Timerange`?

Comment: Does `Duty.durationInHours` differ from `Timerange.durationInHours`?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try:

```
if (((Timerange) Timerange.longest(breaks)).durationInHours() >= MIN_FREE_HOURS)
    return true;
```

e.g., cast it?

Comment: It is OK, but i need to know WHY? :).

Comment: So from that we can conclude that longest isn't returning a Timerange, but something that's compatible with Timerange (otherwise the cast and the assignment would have failed).  Why might that be?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably somewhere in your code you are getting a warning. Listen to your compiler.

To get details add `-Xlint` (in particular `-Xlint:unchecked`) to your javac commandline (or do your development environment's equivalent).